# Applying exactly same WEKA filter on train and test data (What to use in setinputFormat traindata or test data) )

Tags: weka, filter

I am using WEKA for classification.  I need to perform pre-processing before it. I want to do three thing , tf-idf conversion, normalization and discretization. But I want exactly same pre-processing for training and test dataset. After some search I came up with following code. Does any one have any idea if this is the correct way of doing it. Thanks!

```
  public void read_file()
  {    
       try 
    {

        trainsource = new DataSource(source_file_path);
        trains = trainsource.getDataSet();
        trains.setClassIndex(0);

        testsource = new DataSource(target_file_path);
        tests = testsource.getDataSet();
        tests.setClassIndex(0);

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}



     // This function is used to pre-process the dataset
     public void pre_process_data()
  {

  try
    {


      //1. TF-IDF
      StringToWordVector tfidf_filter = new StringToWordVector();
      tfidf_filter.setIDFTransform(true);
      tfidf_filter.setInputFormat(trains);
      trains = Filter.useFilter(trains, tfidf_filter);


      tests = Filter.useFilter(tests, tfidf_filter);



     //2. Normalization           
      Normalize  nor_filter =  new Normalize();
      nor_filter.setInputFormat(trains);
      trains= Filter.useFilter(trains,nor_filter);


      tests= Filter.useFilter(tests,nor_filter);



     //3. Discretizations
      Discretize dfilter = new Discretize();
      dfilter.setInputFormat(trains);
      trains = Filter.useFilter(trains, dfilter);

      tests = Filter.useFilter(tests, dfilter);




    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Please let me know if anyone have any idea about it. Thank You.

Comment: Both train and test need the same pre processing. Your code appears ok. Are you seeing very different scores on train and test datasets?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I was feeling confused in function setInputFormat(trains). I was not getting whether to set input format as trains   or test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInputFormat is the right API to inform the filter about the dataset used (to filter on).

Your code is correct, in setting the train, test datasets using setInputFormat on the Filter.